# Mock up an angular module so a factory can be tested

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test a service without depending on my application module. How is this supposed to work?

Code:

```
#karma.conf.coffee
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js'   # angular core
  'bower_components/**/angular-*.js'      # all angular plugins
  'utils/typometer.js'
  'utils/typometer.spec.js'
]

# utils/typometer.coffee
angular.module('myApp').factory 'typometer', ->
  @sizes =
    'A':8
    'B':9
  @ # return `this`

# utils/typometer.spec.coffee
describe 'typometer', ->
  typometer = undefined # scope control
  # Create a mock module so that the typometer factory has something to attach to
  beforeEach angular.mock.module 'myApp' #TODO: why doesn't mock.module work?
  # Inject the typometer service
  beforeEach angular.mock.inject (_typometer_) ->
    typometer = _typometer_ # http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject

  it 'exists', ->
    expect(typometer).toBeDefined() # fail. 'Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'coatue' is not available!'
    expect(typometer.sizes.A).toEqual 8
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to instantiate a `typometer` service and test it in isolation without standing up a real instance of the `myApp` module.

I think this is some kind of order of operations issue. When the typometer factory is declared, the module doesn't exist--I want to test my production files though. Do I have to create a shell application or load the real one before loading any of the files under test? This is a dependency that I would like to remove from the test considerations.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you explicitly need access to the module itself?

Comment: I don't need access the module, I would like for my factory to be able to create itself though. Updated to use real intended use for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now. For a working setup, one needs to perform all of the following:

1. Load angular + angular plugins
2. Load dependent module definitions (eg: `myApp`). This is what I missed.
3. Load files to test
4. Load specs
5. Have test specs instantiate dependent modules and injectables under test

This is a working setup:

```
#karma.conf.coffee
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js'   # angular core
  'bower_components/**/angular-*.js'      # all angular plugins
      'main.js'                               # still need to load the app definition
  'utils/typometer.js'
  'utils/typometer.spec.js'
]

# utils/typometer.coffee
angular.module('myApp').factory 'typometer', ->
  @sizes =
    'A':8
    'B':9
  @ # return `this`

# utils/typometer.spec.coffee
describe 'typometer', ->
  typometer = undefined # scope control
  beforeEach ->
    angular.mock.module 'myApp' # instantiate the mock app
    angular.mock.inject (_typometer_) -> # instantiate the mock service
      typometer = _typometer_ # http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject

  it 'exists', ->
    expect(typometer).toBeDefined()
    expect(typometer.sizes.A).toEqual 8
```